# dataTaskWithRequest VS sendAsynchronousRequest in iOS8/9 using Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

Having an app written in Objective-C targeting iOS8/9 there are real vantange in performance or stability updating code using  NSURLSession

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                        NSURLResponse *response,
                                        NSError *error) {

                        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                              //UPDATE UI

                        });

                    }] resume];
```

in place of code like the following that use NSURLConnection:

```
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[CMRequestManager connectionQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {


         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             //UPDATE UI

         });

     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to run the code in a WatchKit extension or on tvOS at some point in the future, then yes.  Otherwise, if the snippet above is representative of the way you're using the API, then I probably wouldn't bother rewriting it.  With that said, this is very much a matter of opinion.

Comment: In your opinion is there a scenario where NSURLRequest is "better" than NSURLSession?

Comment: You mean NSURLConnection, I assume—NSURLRequest is used by both APIs.  No, nothing comes to mind other than maintaining compatibility with existing complex code without having to rewrite all of your delegate methods.  Otherwise, NSURLSession does everything that NSURLConnection does, plus a lot more.